# Magento 2.3 : Css files not generating while static content deploy

Tags: magento2, css

In File.php line 150:

The contents from the

```
"D:/projects/directory/m2/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-l.css" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(D:/projects/directory/m2/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-l.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directorysetup:static-content:deploy [-f|--force] [-s|--strategy [STRATEGY]] [-a|--area [AREA]] [--exclude-area [EXCLUDE-AREA]] [-t|--theme [THEME]] [--exclude-theme [EXCLUDE-THEME]] [-l|--language [LANGUAGE]] [--exclude-language [EXCLUDE-LANGUAGE]] [-j|--jobs [JOBS]] [--symlink-locale] [--content-version CONTENT-VERSION] [--refresh-content-version-only] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [--] [<languages>...]
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of already theme insert your theme information after that deploy it.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --exclude-theme Magento/luma --no-html-minify
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing same issue on Magento 2.3, all pub/static directory seems to be in order apart from a missing css directory and styles.css

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of a compilation error in the css. Its failing and then something next in the chain is erroring because a css file is missing. This can be a pain to debug. Have you tried running static content deploy with show errors. Failing that dump php output to file.

`php -d display_errors=1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php -d bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy > output.log`

Comment: Could be an inheritance problem. You might need to put empty styles-l.css in your theme.

Comment: Thanks guys i have create empty css files which are notified as missing.

Comment: Is this worked?